# Check for change in inner html by html Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently load a html page into a `<DIV>` in my page. using this code

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'myApi.php?user=' + user + '&url='+ URL2add, 
        success: function(html) {                    
            var newHTML = "<object id='webloader' data='" + html + "'></object>";
            $("#exweb").fadeOut(500, function () {
                $("#exweb").html(newHTML).fadeIn(5000, function() {
                    alert("done");
                });
            });
        }
});
```

So i want to do a check or preferably get a alert once that page loaded changes. which is in the data tag  that comes from the `html` coining back from the ajax call.

I have tried `document.getElementsByTagName`

I know there has to be a way to get the new data info in that object .

i would prefer an alert each time the page changes from what comes back from the ajax call

i have updated the code like this...

```
 $(document).on('contentchanged', '#exweb', function() {

        alert('WOO?');
    });

     $.ajax({
                url: 'Api.php?user=' + user + '&url='+ URL2add, 
                success: function(html) {                    
                var newHTML = "<object id='webloader' data='" + html + "'></object>";
                $("#exweb").fadeOut(50, function () {
                    $("#exweb").html(newHTML).fadeIn(50, function() {
                    $('#exweb').trigger('contentchanged');

                            });
                    });
                }     
                });
```

But this is only working on initial change

i need to know when that  page changes again.. say if someone clicks on a link that will change the page in DIV  or if its a redirect page.

i want to know whenever that page changes to something after i loaded it from my ajax call

should it not be as easy as getting the information between data=""

```
<object id="webloader" data="http://google.com"></object>
```

and how do i get back that info?  i have tried `document.getElementsByTagName`

Comment: So you want a callback for Ajax completion?

Comment: i want to be able to check if page has changed after ajax call is already done.  there mus be a way to be able to find  the url of most current page in the data=

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: can you help me understand how to get that to work with my example code?  cause i am NOT seeing the solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this after ajax.

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function() {
alert('page loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this `$("div").load("your_url.php?parameters");` the page you want to load could have the following `<body onload="alert('Page Loaded')">`
Update:- if you dont have the access of the webpage then use this `$("div").load("your_url.php?parameters",function(){alert("Page loaded")});`

Comment: what if i do not have control over page loaded?

Comment: then use `$("div").load("your_url.php?parameters",function(){alert("page loaded");});`

Comment: can you check my updated code and see if that could still work cause i cant incorporate it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({/* your AJAX */}).done(function() {
  alert(/*your text*/"page loaded!");
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.